# Spring (Boot) ignores my log4j.properties file

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I wanted to use logging in my implementation. I've set the log4j.properties to logging in both the console and the file:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE, FILE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# CONSOLE uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.home}/logs/smartcv.log

# Set the immediate flush to true (default)
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# Set the threshold to debug mode
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

And here's my main application class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class SmartcvfrontApplication {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SmartcvfrontApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.debug("Debug log message");
        logger.info("Info log message");
        logger.error("Error log message");
        SpringApplication.run(SmartcvfrontApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now, it doesn't matter in which folder of my project I put the properties, or even completely remove it - the logs will show up in my console, but no file is created.
This and the fact I can completely remove the properties make me suspect that Spring Boot is just flat out ignoring the properties file and just using a basic configuration.

Does anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

UPDATE: I followed the answer and now the file is on my C drive while I thought it would be in my project. Is this supposed to happen or did I go wrong?
Also, when I want to log from another class like my ThermostatController it doesn't add that to the log files... What am I doing wrong here?
Here's part of the ThermostatController class:

```
@Controller
public class ThermostatController {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ThermostatController.class);

    // Temperatures
    private static int currentTemperature;
    private static int chosenTemperature;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String loadThermostatView(Model model) {
        logger.info("Load ThermostatView");
        model.addAttribute("currentTemperature", getcurrentTemp());
        model.addAttribute("chosenTemperature", getchosenTemperature());
        return "thermostatView";
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's my pom.xml just to clarify.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.cgimasterclass.teamdice.smartcv.frontend</groupId>
    <artifactId>smartcvfront</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>smartcvfront</name>
    <description>Smart CV front end</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.4</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Put `log4j.properties` file under `src/resources` folder.

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV Did that, still no log file.

Comment: then better you add the logging configuration in `application.properties` file.

Comment: Remove your `log4j.properties`. Spring boot by default uses logback not LOg4j. If you want to control the level of logging just modify it in your `application.properties` with `logging.level.your.logger.here=level`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and the follow solution **didn't help me**...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

... so I tried replace it with next one

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

and it worked! ... If issue is still actual - try it! Maybe this way will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration seems to be right. If you have put the properties file in the right path, then there may be something wrong with your dependencies. Then replace your dependency with the following and try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, I did this. Then it was asking for the log4j.properties so I places those in src/main/resources as that was the only time I did not get `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.cgimasterclass.teamdice.smartcv.frontend.smartcvfront.SmartcvfrontApplication).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`  Yet still, there's no log file in my project.

Comment: Nevermind, the file is there but it's on my C drive instead of in my project, where I thought it would be.......

Comment: And it now only logs from my SmartcvApplication class, not from my Controller class (see edit of original post).

Comment: I am not sure what's going wrong with you, it works perfectly in my spring boot project. But the log file would be created at `log4j.appender.FILE.File`.